# Kotlin data class, copy field values of one data class to another data class with same fields

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi i have a data class `Books` with some fields like id, name, price etc. I have another data class `LocalBooks` with exactly `same` fields like class `Books`. I want to copy all the values of `Books` data class fields to fields of `LocalBooks`. I tried this way. This is good to go when you have just few fields but when you have more fields above 20 or greater then following this method is time consuming. I wanted to know if there is any method in kotlin which can help in this purpose.

```
data class Books(val name: String, val price: Int) : Serializable
data class LocalBooks(val name: String, val price: Int) : Serializable
val books = Books("Book1", 22)
val localBooks = LocalBooks(books.name, books.price)
```

Comment: "I have another data class LocalBooks with exactly same fields like class Books" -- why? Why not have one `Books` class that has an `isLocal: Boolean = false` property that you set to `true` for local books? If you do that, then a simple `copy()` is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Or you can even extend your "Books" class in case you don't want to have a solution as the comment above.

Comment: You may use reflection. Or dismiss classes completely and use `Map` implementation to mimic dynamic languages behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about a *composite reuse principle* solution:

```
data class Book(val name: String, val price: Int)
data class LocalBook(val book: Book, val localInfo: String)
val book = Book("foo", 1)
val localBook = LocalBook(book.copy(), "bar")
```

Comment: hi what is "bar" here?

Comment: hi. just a throwaway placeholder value for `LocalBook`'s `localInfo`  property.